# Why is it that the texture isn´t loading? Minecraft 15.2 Forge 31.2

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to apply a texture to an item created with forge for Minecraft but for some reason it wouldn´t load. I am new to this so I cant recognize where the problem is, so I will upload multiple lines of code.
This code is from itemInit.Java:

```
package com.example.examplemod.init;
    
import com.example.examplemod.ExampleMod;

import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemGroup;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventBusSubscriber.Bus;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ObjectHolder;
import net.minecraftforge.event.RegistryEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.SubscribeEvent;


@Mod.EventBusSubscriber(modid = ExampleMod.MOD_ID, bus = Bus.MOD)
@ObjectHolder(ExampleMod.MOD_ID)
public class itemInit {
    public static Item example_item = null;
    
    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void registerItems(final RegistryEvent.Register<Item> event) {
        event.getRegistry().register(new Item(new Item.Properties().group(ItemGroup.MISC)).setRegistryName("example_item"));
    }
}
```

This is the example_item.json:

```
{
    "parent":"items/generated",
    "textures":{
    "layer0":"examplemod:items/example_item"
    }
}
```

en_us.json:

```
{
    "item.examplemod.example_item":"Super Seed"
}
```

And here is a picture of the project hierarchy:[Project hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2MHF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example_mod.json file, line 2, change it to

```json
"parent": "item/generated",
```

Inside the directory assets\examplemod\models, you have two folders named blocks and items. Change their names to 'block' and 'item' without the quotation marks. If you encounter any other problem, post your error log using pastebin or some other site. Also, create a github repo for your project and then post the link here :)

Also, I recommend using DeferredRegister class and RegistryObjects to register your custom items.
Syntax:

```java
public static final DeferredRegister<Item> NAME = new DeferredRegister<>(ForgeRegistries.ITEMS, "Your Mod ID");
   
public static final RegistryObject<Item> Example_item = NAME.register("Registry_Name", () -> new Item(new Item.Properties()));
```

Comment: By the way, if this answer solves your problem, mark this as accepted so that it may help others too :)